# Stripping quotes in a for / findstr loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, findstr

I am trying to process a text file that looks like this:

```
"N" "accounts" "General" no "0001"
"N" "accounts" "Customer" no "0002" 
and so on
```

The batch file looks like this:

```batch-file
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set TGT=schctrl
set TMP=schctrl.tmp

copy %TGT% %TMP%

set NWOV=accounts inventory generalledger headoffice

for %%a in (%NWOV%) do (
   
   for /f "tokens=2,5 delims= " %%D in ('findstr /i %%a %TMP%') do (
      set M=%%E
      set M=%M:"=%
      echo %%D %%E %M%
   )
)
```

The command, `set M=%M:"=%`, doesn't strip off all the quotation marks!

When I run it, I get output like this:

```
set M="1148"
set M=!M:"=!
echo "accounts" "1148"
```

I am expecting the last line to look like this:

```
"accounts" "1148" 1148
```

The last field is missing.

I am guessing the culprit is the `for` loop, and expansion of variables, but I have been grinding away on this and have not yet found the solution.

Comment: `tmp` and `temp` are variablenames that both, for historical reasons, contain the location of a temporary directory by default. It is unwise to use these (amongst others) as user-variables. Also, the reason why "it doesn't" is explained here: [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

Comment: wait - when executing `set M=%M:"=%`, you get `set M=!M:"=!`? Recheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open `cmd` and run `for /?`. Scroll down to the section on `Substitution` and read the first line:
[image]
Therefore `%%E` will contain quotes and `%%~E` won't contain quotes. So, just changing that meta variable in the code:

```
@echo off

set "TGT=schctrl"
set "TMP_FILE=schctrl.tmp"

copy "%TGT%" "%TMP_FILE%"

set "NWOV=accounts inventory generalledger headoffice"

for %%a in (%NWOV%) do (
   for /f "tokens=2,5 delims= " %%D in ('findstr /i %%a %TMP_FILE%') do (
      echo %%D %%E %%~E
   )
)
```

As a side note, the reason why your search/replace did not work is because you `enable`d `delayedexpansion` but you never used it. For that you needed to replace `%` with `!` in the variables you are expanding within the loop, so `!M!` instead of `%M%`

That being said, please do not use single characters as variable names it will create confusion.
Also, as stated by Magoo in the comments, do not re-use system variables, like `%TMP%`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - your input is greatly appreciated. I am comfortable at the bash shell but Windows is rather an arcane subject to me.